# mdx calculated measure versus measure

Tags: mdx

just wondering if you could explain to me why these two mdx statements yield different results, and how I would alter the calculated measure to be correct. I am assuming the calculated measure is incorrectly using the sum function.

```
SELECT    
{ 
[Measures].[PPPH]
} 
ON COLUMNS,  
{
[Matter].[Parent Matter Lawyer - Responsible].&[qnas]
}
ON ROWS  
FROM [Expert Hypercube] 
WHERE   
(  
[Date].[Fiscal].[Month].&[201702], 
[Relative Period].[Relative Period].&[YTD]
)
```

versus

```
with 
member measures.[PPPHx] as 
  sum({{linkmember([Timekeeper].[Person].currentmember,[Matter].[Parent Matter Lawyer - Responsible])}},measures.[PPPH])
select
{
measures.[PPPHx]
} on columns, 
{
[Timekeeper].[Person].&[qnas]
} on rows
from [Expert Hypercube]
where
(
[Date].[Fiscal].[Month].&[201702], 
[Relative Period].[Relative Period].&[YTD]
)
```

Comment: And which one is correct?

Comment: What's [Matter].[Parent Matter Lawyer - Responsible]? Is it just an attribute hierarchy (All member and single level) or is it a multi-level hierarchy? LinkMember just looks for the first member with key "qnas" without regard to level.

Comment: Hi @planetmaker, the top one is correct.

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway, it is a singe level attribute heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why do you use **Sum** function at all. **LinkMember** function returns a member, no need to cover it with {...} like a set. Also you need to use the All member, since it returns *[Timekeeper].[Person].CurrentMember* + *LinkMember([Timekeeper].[Person].CurrentMember,[Matter].[Parent Matter Lawyer - Responsible])*.

```
With 
Member [Measures].[PPPHx] as 
(
    LinkMember([Timekeeper].[Person].CurrentMember,[Matter].[Parent Matter Lawyer - Responsible]),
    [Timekeeper].[Person].[All],
    [Measures].[PPPH]
)
```

See a [Richard Lees's article about it](http://richardlees.blogspot.com/2011/06/linkmember.htmL).

Comment: Thanks Danylo, very helpful.